# Value addition in existing table datagridview in C#

Tags: c#

I have added many times, but the values do not added show in the datagrid. I don't know where the problem is.

Why is this not working?  The left side value of table also added but that value does not show added.

The table also exists that is linked with the database.

```
total_price1 = Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridViewMemos.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value.ToString()) * Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridViewMemos.Rows[index].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
this.dataGridViewMemos.Rows[index].cells[0].value = total_price1.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi,
Is it any error you encounter when you run this code? 
or it simply does not sum up the value?
Can you explain what is the use case and which type of application (web or windows) it is?

Comment: It is doing sum up values but do not show in table

Comment: It is window form application. I have been try many things change but do not show me eror.i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Is it possible to share your code of data fetching from database and binding it to the gridview? With this couple of lines of code it's difficult to understand the use case and cause of the problem. Thanks

Comment: if i do this it  show a database table values in datagrid  view . it also multiply and show in table 8 colums like this : Cells[ 8 ].Value=total_price1  . If i do this same as in cells[0].value=total_price1. it is new table colum cell value.It colum is not conected with database.But colum 8 is conected with database . i dont know where is

Comment: Yes this is code of problem.Yes this is code of problem. cmd is a mysqlcommand and return after exection this command from database class.

Comment: objDB = new DataBaseClass ( );cmd = objDB.displayMemo();      dataTable = new DataTable ( );
            mySqlAdaptor = new MySqlDataAdapter ( cmd );
            mySqlAdaptor.Fill ( dataTable );
            dataGridViewMemos.DataSource = dataTable;
            memosReportpanel.BringToFront ( );
            addMemoPanel.SendToBack ( );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been fixed this error. We will put the select query to add two columns or multiply two columns values and then alias it. This alias name put on `DataGridView` column.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(colum1, colum2) AS sum, 
    (colum1* colum2) AS multiply
FROM 
    tableDB
```

Remember that you will put alias name on the `DataGridView` columns.